# Reference for: smooth projective curve minus a point is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

Does anybody know a textbook or journal reference which contains the proof of the "well-known" fact that a  smooth projective curve minus a point (or even finitely many points) is affine? The proof appears here on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594240/must-a-proper-curve-minus-a-point-be-affine) multiple times, in Ravi Vakil's [notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/725/class25.pdf) (but not in his book, at far as I can tell) and other discussion forums. I need something citable. The case of elliptic curves would suffice.

Comment: I thought it was in Görtz/Wedhorn, §15.5, but it's not. You can always cite Hartshorne, Exercise IV.1.4, but I suppose that's not ideal…

Comment: A point on a curve is an ample divisor, and the complement of an ample divisor is always affine.

Comment: @Sasha: I am looking for a reference which is citable.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama: Thank you. This is in fact not ideal, because it is an exercise.

Comment: Seems relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594240/must-a-proper-curve-minus-a-point-be-affine?noredirect=1&lq=1

(note that projective $\Rightarrow$ proper)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is practically Sasha's proof, but you can cite Proposition 5 in:

> Goodman, Jacob Eli. "Affine open subsets of algebraic varieties and ample divisors." *Ann. of Math. (2)* 89 (1969), pp. 160–183. DOI: [10.2307/1970814](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970814). MR: [0242843](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=242843).

Comment: Thank you. But why should a curve minus a point be proper? Prop. 5 assumes a proper open subscheme.

Comment: @HeinrichD By "proper open" Goodman means that the open set in question is not equal to the whole curve.

Comment: Ah, I was mixing up the two meanings of "proper". Thank you for clearing this up. I should have noticed this because the paper uses the term "complete".