# Some properties of the Fermat hypersurfaces $X_0^d + \cdots + X_{n+1}^{d}=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Fix two integers $n \geq 1$ and $d \geq 2$. Let $X_{n,d} \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$ be the Fermat hypersurface defined by the equation
$$
F_{n,d}: X_0^{d}+ \cdots + X_{n+1}^{d} = 0.
$$
One can check that it is nonsingular of dimension $n$. In the exam (**EDIT**: This is from an exam paper in 2017, so this post is not cheating), I was asked to consider the following problem:

**Question**: Let $p \in X_{n,d}$ be any point. Show that $X_{n,d} \smallsetminus \{p\}$ is not projective. When is it affine?

I managed to see why it is not projective, but got stuck on considering its affineness.

**My attempts**: When $n \geq 2$, the singleton $\{p\}$ has codimension $\geq 2$ in $X_{n,d}$. Hence by the *Hartog extension theorem*, the inclusion $i: X_{n,d} \smallsetminus \{p\} \hookrightarrow X_{n,d}$ induces an isomorphism
$$
i^{\sharp}: \Gamma(X_{n,d}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{n,d}}) \rightarrow \Gamma(X_{n,d} \smallsetminus \{p\}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{n,d} \smallsetminus \{p\}})
$$
so the global section of $X_{n,d} \smallsetminus \{p\}$ is $k$. If it were affine, then its dimension could be calculated by the Krull dimension of the global section, hence its dimension would be zero, which is absurd. Hence it is not affine.

**However**, when $n=1$, the Hartog extension theorem is not applicable. Then I do not know what to do. When $n=1$ and $d=2$, if we use the "*huge input*" that every nonsingular conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, then we see $X_{1,2} \smallsetminus \{p\}$ is affine, isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. But how about the general degree $d > 2$?

(And as for the "huge input", I do not want to use it since the only proof of it I know is to see both the nonsingular conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ has genus zero, and all genus zero curves are isomorphic by Riemann-Roch. So can we get rid of this input or can we use a more elementary approach for this "huge input"?)

Thank you so much for answering and commenting! Happy new year!

Comment: I think what you said in your attempt is right, and that you reduced it to the case that $X$ is a degree $d$ fermat plane curve. However the fermat cubic curve is elliptic so it shouldn't be isomorphic (or even birational) to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your hints! Yet what do you mean by saying *elliptic*? I can see that for degree $d \geq 3$ curve $X_{1,d}$, it has genus $>0$ hence not birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Yet how does this lead to the conclusion that $X_{1,d} \smallsetminus \{p\}$ is not affine? Though $X_{1,d} \smallsetminus \{p\}$ seems not being $\mathbb{A}^1$, how can we exclude the possibility that it is actually some affine variety contained properly in $\mathbb{A}^1$, or that even in higher $\mathbb{A}^m$? Thank you!

Comment: I noted that someone gave a downvote of this post. Might you explain the reason so that I can better improve the post?

Comment: Every line and every smooth plane conic isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1$ not cubic

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah, so sorry I made such a serious typo. So I mean every smooth conic, i.e. a degree $2$ nonsingular curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Thank you and also thanks yi li for pointing that out!

Comment: It is affine in the rest of the cases. A projective curve minus a point is affine.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you so much! I found these discussions on the fact you provided: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977248 . Thanks! :)