# Elliptic curves - "Important exercise" 19.10.F in Vakil's note

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I have been learning recently about elliptic curves, and I am totally new in this topic. I just followed the construction of the group-scheme structure on elliptic curves given by Vakil in his notes (that you can find [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf)). Right after this, he gives a pretty concrete exercise (page 522) for which I would like some hints as to how to solve it efficiently.

Here is the statement of the exercise.

> Let $k$ be a field. Consider the genus $1$ curve $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2_k$  given by 
>   $$y^2z=x^3+x^2z$$
>   with the point $\mathbb{p}=[0,1,0]$. Emulate "the above argument" to show that $C \setminus \{[0,0,1]\}$ is a group variety. Show that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m$ (the multiplicative group-scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(k[t,t^{-1}])$) with coordinate $t=\frac{y}{x}$ by giving an isomorphism of schemes, and showing that multiplication and inverse in both group-varieties agree under this isomorphism.

Okay, there are multiple things going on here. I am going to ask a few questions about this. Some of them may be pretty basic, but I think that this exercise would is a perfect occasion to clear up a few confusions in my mind about basic computations in algebraic geometry. In the following, let $U$ denote $C \setminus \{[0,0,1]\}$.

**First**, to justify that $U$ has a natural structure of scheme, I prove that $[0,0,1]$ is a closed point by computing its residue field in the distinguished open set $z\not = 0$. Here, $C$ becomes the affine curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k=\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y])$ and the point we are interested in is $(0,0)$. Its residue field is the quotient field of the integral domain $A/(x,y)$, where $A=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$. This integral domain actually already is a field, none other than $k$. As a result, $[0,0,1]$ is a closed point of $C$ of degree $1$.
Is this method the correct way to proceed? Is there a more straightforward way to see it?

**Second**, to show that $U$ comes with a structure of group-variety, I actually need to show that it is a subgroup-scheme of $C$, ie that it is stable under the group laws and contains the neutral point $\mathbb{p}$. Actually, I do not really understand which "*above argument*" Vakil is refering to here. From what I can tell, I have to check by hand that whenever I consider a point in $U$ and look at the line joining it to $\mathbb{p}$, then the third point of intersection with $C$ can not be $[0,0,1]$ ; and the same goes whenever I consider the line joining two arbitrary points of $U$.
I think I have actually been able to show the first part, but this is quite fastidious and I feel like there must be another way to check this properly. How would you treat this part of the exercise?

**Third**, to build the scheme-theoretic morphism between $U$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$, it is enough to give a $k$-linear morphism $k[t,t^{-1}]\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{U}(U)$. Now, I notice that $U$ is just the union of the distinguished open sets $x\not = 0$ and $y \not = 0$, intersected with $C$. The global sections of $U$ are the pairs of global sections on each of these open sets that agree on the intersection. Global sections on each of the open sets are given by a quotient of polynomials whose denominator is non-vanishing. So I see that I could send $t$ to the pair $(\frac{y}{x},\frac{x}{y})$, but these do not agree on the intersection as far as I can tell.
How does one makes sense of the statement $t=\frac{y}{x}$ given in the exercise as a hint?

**Fourth**, I know as a general result that a proper geometrically connected curve over a field becomes affine when a finite nonzero number of points are omitted from it (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594240/must-a-proper-curve-minus-a-point-be-affine)). Hence, it is not surprizing to see that it applies for $U$. However, is there a way to compute this affine space easily in conrete examples? Just by seeing the equation and the point we are omitting, is there a way to guess that we will obtain something nice like $\operatorname{Spec}(k[t,t^{-1}])$? How does one infer what the ring must look like?

Thank you very much for reading through this. Any clarification for any of the above points will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comment, $C$ is not a group-scheme, hence my second point reasoning makes no sense. Let me then replace my second point with the following: in order to show that $U$ is a group-scheme, can I simply argue that $U$ is an elliptic curve, because it is obtained by removing the singular point(s) of a genus $1$ projective curve described by a Weierstraß type equation? If so, this part of the exercise now becomes trivial. What is important is to understand why the group-structure behaves like $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: Your second point is not correct. $C$ is NOT a group scheme, only $U$ is. May be the easiest path is to show that the normalization of $C$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$ and the fiber over $[0,0.1]$ is two points and outside it is an isomorphism. Then, $U$ is just the projective line minus two points ($k$-rational) which has the structure of the multiplicative group scheme.

Comment: @Mohan So $C$ is not a group-scheme? I am a little confused. The data of $C$ together with the $k$-point $\mathbb{p}$ is an elliptic curve, right? Why is there no group-scheme structure defined on it? (Would it be because $[0,0,1]$ is not regular?)

Comment: Ok, I have convinced myself that it is indeed not regular, hence one would have to remove it in order to get an elliptic curve. So I see that any genus $1$ curve described by the Weierstraß normal form is not necessarily an elliptic curve as a whole - one may need to remove singular points for this. I was absolutely not aware of this fact.

Comment: A singular cubic is never an elliptic curve. Even if you remove the singular point, you only get a rational curve, never an elliptic curve even birationally.

Comment: I see. I am going to ask another question about the Weierstraß form then, because I feel a little confused about it. My misunderstanding may come from this confusion.