# Why are the modular curves affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

I recently heard that the modular curves $Y(\Gamma)$ are affine, which is surprising for me (I wasn't expecting that at all).

Why is it true? Is true for other Shimura varieties?

Comment: What is the definition of the modular curve that you are using? Do you know about the j-invariant? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant

Comment: Hi, I think the definition doesn't matter right? 
If either (a quotient of) the Poincaré half plane, or a finite number of copies of that (i.e. the adelic definition) is affine then the other will be right? Even if we consider the moduli spaces of elliptic curves: it is affine iif its complex points form an affine variety right?

I know about the $j$-invariant, but I dont know how it helps to show the affineness...

Comment: No, if you do not know an actual definition, you cannot prove anything. From what you wrote, a modular curve could as well be projective, not affine!

Comment: Ok, so I'm interested in basically every case, but we can begin with the moduli space of elliptic curve with level $N$ structure (over the cyclotomic extension).

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594240/must-a-proper-curve-minus-a-point-be-affine. Modular curves have cusps, hence they are affine.

Comment: (Most Shimura varieties are neither affine nor projective, but curves are just easy.)

Comment: Ooooh I see, thank you it's very enlightening!!